# How to get all the components of the table without the first column in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello my office the next, I happen to have a table generated in html, but I want to capture all the structure of the table without considering the entire first column, until now could only manage to capture all components in a variable, but I need to improve it to capture all but the first column of the table.

**.html**

```
<table border="1" id="tblConsulta">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
            <th>Dependencia</th>
            <th>UU.OO</th>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Reg</th>
            <th>Responsable</th>
            <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
            <th>Fecha Fin</th>
            <th>Fecha Autoriz</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Motivo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="editor-active" value="74" disabled="" type="checkbox" /></td>   
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
var output = '';

$("[id=tblConsulta]").each(function() {
    output += $(this).find("thead").html();
    $('#tblConsulta tbody tr').each(function() {
        var j = 0;
        output += '<tr class="">';
        $.each(this.cells, function() {
            j++;
            if (j < 12) {
                if (j == 5) {
                    output += '<td class="date">';
                } else if (j == 3) {
                    output += '<td class="number">';
                } else {
                    output += '<td class="text">';
                    output += $(this).html();
                    output += '</td>';
                }
            }
        });
        output += '</tr>';
    });
});

console.log(output);
```

I hope you can help me, the idea is to capture the chexbox not want to label in the chain, because then I want to print it in a report.

I have also published jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/movboj2m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try straight up removing the first column from the table, after having saved it first. Then after your log is printed, put the table back in its original condition, aka:

```js
var output = '';
var saveTable = $("table").html();

$("table").find("th:first").remove();
$("table").find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td:first").remove();
});

$("[id=tblConsulta]").each(function() {
    output += $(this).find("thead").html();
    $('#tblConsulta tbody tr').each(function() {
        var j = 0;
        output += '<tr class="">';
        $.each(this.cells, function() {
            j++;
            if (j < 12) {
                if (j == 5) {
                    output += '<td class="date">';
                } else if (j == 3) {
                    output += '<td class="number">';
                } else {
                    output += '<td class="text">';
                    output += $(this).html();
                    output += '</td>';
                }
            }
        });
        output += '</tr>';
    });
});

console.log(output);
$("table").html(saveTable);
```

```css
 .title{
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .index {
 
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
 }
 
 .prev {
 
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
 }
 
 .next {
 
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
 }
 
 .clicked{
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #993333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
 }
 
 .enter{
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 
 #result1{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tblConsulta">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
            <th>Dependencia</th>
            <th>UU.OO</th>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Reg</th>
            <th>Responsable</th>
            <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
            <th>Fecha Fin</th>
            <th>Fecha Autoriz</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Motivo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="editor-active" value="74" disabled="" type="checkbox" /></td>   
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tblConsulta tr:gt(1)`. **gt** selector: https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: This handles the first row, but I think OP wants to exclude the first column.